# website content is null

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.murarilal.asynktask;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task=new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=59b308aec9f242fe98b527ab9ba93199");
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String result = "";

            URL url;

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {

                url = new URL(strings[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Log.i("website content",""+result);
        }
    }
}
```

**i m not able to get the website content**

**11-04 16:14:55.703 14245-14366/com.example.murarilal.asynktask W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9d728fa0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
11-04 16:14:55.713 14245-14366/com.example.murarilal.asynktask D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d7042a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d703290)
11-04 16:14:56.381 14245-14256/com.example.murarilal.asynktask I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=42KB
11-04 16:14:56.384 14245-14256/com.example.murarilal.asynktask I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=53KB, data=37KB
11-04 16:14:56.384 14245-14256/com.example.murarilal.asynktask I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
11-04 16:14:57.325 14245-14245/com.example.murarilal.asynktask I/website content: null**

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Which device you are running?

Comment: actually i am trying to get json data from website in log window

Answer (score 0):

Go to **AVD Manager**, edit the settings of your emulator, go to Emulated Performance section and change Graphics to **Software GLSE 2.0**